# PHP validation - form not validating

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I am a Java guy and started PHP. This is my first question on PHP.

PLaying with forms. I didn't make it work. The form just not validating and silently submitting. What could be my mistake?

The error messages are not printing up.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="css/program-07.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <div id="requirements" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align:justify; width:850px;">
                <h1></h1>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="sidenav">
                <header class="w3-container">
                <h3>Navigation</h3>
                </header>
                    <a href="http://lineofcode.com/itse2302-002/itse2302-002-007/">Home</a>     
                    <a href="index.php">Program07</a>
                    <a target="_blank" href="selfprocessor.php">Self Processor</a>
                    <a target="_blank" href="validatecontrols.php">Validate Controls</a>
            </nav>

            <div id="main" style="margin-left:25%">

            <?php
                echo "<h2>Requirement 01 - Datalists + Navigation</h2>";
                echo "<h3>To the left are navigation links to the files in this program, and below (not visible) datalists of the days of the week and months of the year that will be used in requirement 2.";            ?>


                    <datalist id="daysweek">
                        <option value="Monday">
                        <option value="Tuesday">
                        <option value="Wednesday">
                        <option value="Thursday">
                        <option value="Friday">
                        <option value="Saturday">
                        <option value="Sunday">
                    </datalist>

                    <datalist id="monthsyear">
                        <option value="January">
                        <option value="February">
                        <option value="March">
                        <option value="April">
                        <option value="May">
                        <option value="June">
                        <option value="July">
                        <option value="August">
                        <option value="September">
                        <option value="October">
                        <option value="November">
                        <option value="December">
                    </datalist>

            <?php           
                echo "<hr>";

                echo "<h2>Requirement 02 - Datalists</h2>";
                echo "<h3>The two datalists from above are now incorporated into a form that the user can see and interact with.</h3>";
                echo "Input a day of the week and a month of the year.";
            ?> 
                    <form action="daymonth.php" method="get">
                      <input list="daysweek" name="days">
                        <datalist id="day">
                          <option value="Monday">
                          <option value="Tuesday">
                          <option value="Wednesday">
                          <option value="Thursday">
                          <option value="Friday">
                          <option value="Saturday">
                          <option value="Sunday">
                        </datalist>

                        <input list="monthsyear" name="months">
                            <datalist id="month">
                                <option value="January">
                                <option value="February">
                                <option value="March">
                                <option value="April">
                                <option value="May">
                                <option value="June">
                                <option value="July">
                                <option value="August">
                                <option value="September">
                                <option value="October">
                                <option value="November">
                                <option value="December">
                              </datalist>
                        <input type="submit">
                    </form>

            <?php                 
                echo "<hr>";

                echo "<h2>Requirement 03 - Form Processor</h2>";
                echo "<h3>A form processor file named daymonth was created for the form data in requirement 2.  A function called test_input checks the data for safety.</h3>";

                echo "<hr>";

                echo "<h2>Requirement 04 - Favorites Form</h2>";
                echo "<h3>This form includes required fields.</h3>";

                $nameErr = $movieErr = $foodErr = $seasonErr = "";
                $name = $movie = $food = $season = $comment = "";

                if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                     $nameErr = "Please tell us your name!";
                   } else {
                     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                   }

                   if (empty($_POST["movie"])) {
                     $movieErr = "Please tell us your favorite movie!";
                   } else {
                     $email = test_input($_POST["movie"]);
                   }

                   if (empty($_POST["food"])) {
                     $foodErr = "Please tell us your favorite food!";
                   } else {
                     $website = test_input($_POST["food"]);
                   }

                    if (empty($_POST["season"])) {
                     $seasonErr = "Please tell us your favorite season!";
                   } else {
                     $gender = test_input($_POST["season"]);
                   }

                   if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
                     $comment = "";
                   } else {
                     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
                   }
                }

            ?>
                <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
                <form method="post" action="favorites.php"> 
                    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                    <br><br>
                    Favorite Movie: <input type="text" name="movie">
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $movieErr;?></span>
                    <br><br>
                    Favorite Food: <input type="text" name="food">
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $foodErr;?></span>
                    <br><br>
                    Favorite Season:
                    <input type="radio" name="season" value="Spring">Spring
                    <input type="radio" name="season" value="Summer">Summer
                    <input type="radio" name="season" value="Fall">Fall
                    <input type="radio" name="season" value="Winter">Winter
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $seasonErr;?></span>
                    <br><br>
                    Comments:<br />
                    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
                </form>

               <?php     
                echo "<hr>";

                echo "<h2>Requirement 05 - </h2>";
                echo "<h3></h3>";


                echo "<hr>";

                echo "<h2>Requirement 06 - </h2>";
                echo "<h3></h3>";


                echo "<hr>";

                echo "<h2>Requirement 07 - </h2>";
                    echo "<h3></h3>";


                echo "<hr>";

                echo "<h2>Requirement 08 - </h2>";
                echo "<h3></h3>";

                echo "<hr>";

                echo "<h2>Requirement 09 - </h2>";
                echo "<h3></h3>";


                echo "<hr>";


            ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

And my favorites.php

```
<head>
    <title>Program 07 - Nicola Stewart</title>
    <link href="css/program-07.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <div id="daymonth" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align:justify; width:850px;">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="sidenav" style="width:25%">
        <header class="w3-container">
        <h3>Navigation</h3>
        </header>
        <a href="http://lineofcode.com/itse2302-002/itse2302-002-007/">Home</a>     
        <a href="index.php">Program07</a>           
  </nav>

    <div id="main" style="margin-left:25%">

        <h2>Requirement 04 - Favorites Form</h2>

        <header class="container">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="container">

        <?php
            $name = $movie = $food = $season = $comment = "";

            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                $movie = test_input($_POST["movie"]);
                $food = test_input($_POST["food"]);
                $season = test_input($_POST["season"]);
                $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);

            }

            function test_input($data) {
               $data = trim($data);
               $data = stripslashes($data);
               $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
               return $data;
            }

            echo "<h2>You selected:</h2>";
            echo "<h3>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo $name;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $movie;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $food;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $season;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $comment;
            echo "</h3>";
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Is this the code for `favorites.php`?

Comment: @grim This is my index.php. Giving that faviourates.php.

Comment: I've done a few updates to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting your form data to `favorites.php`

```
<form method="post" action="favorites.php"> ... </form>
```

Change it to:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php"> ... </form>
```

Or move your form validation to `favorites.php`

If you want to display your form again, I suggest you move the code in charge of the form's HTML to a file by itself (i.e. `form.php`) and then you can do the following in both `index.php` and `favorites.php`:

```
include 'form.php'
```

Note that when you include a PHP file in another, the variables are shared, meaning that you can use/override the variables.

(You can also do the include for the header and footer of the website)

**EDIT (Answering comment)**
Update `test_data()`:

```
function test_input($index) {
  if (isset($_POST[$index])) {  // make sure that the index exists in $_POST
    $data = $_POST[$index];
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }
  return null;  // or any default value
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
$season = test_input("season");
```

**Personal favorite for getting data from a POST or GET:**

[filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

```
$season = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'season', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Comment: Grim, for some reason, facing an issue now When I click submit right now the error on favorites.php is `Notice: Undefined index: season in C:\wamp\www\program-07\favorites.php on line 65"` And that line is `$season = test_input($_POST["season"]);`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Do you have an `input` tag with an attribute `name="season"`? If not, add it to your form. Also you can use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to make sure that your `$_POST` has a specific index (i.e. `if(isset($_POST['season']`)

Comment: Ah.. let me try that. Thanks for the help. Will give a bounty for this :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I also added a personal recommendation to fetch the input from the post. You can use it in your `test_input()` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92677/discussion-between-ss--and-grim).